# How use jtable in PHP mvc1 (zend framework)?

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, model-view-controller, jquery-jtable

I got jtable from jtable.org.

When I use jtable in simple PHP projects it works fine, but when I change it to PHP mvc it returned the following error and it didn't show any data in jtable.

> An error occured while communicating to the server.
>   but in the chrom console it print JSON:

```
{
 "Result":"OK",
 "TotalRecordCount":"20",
 "Records":[
            {"PersonId":"1","0":"1","Name":"Benjamin Button","1":"Benjamin Button","Age":"17","2":"17","RecordDate":"2011-12-27 00:00:00","3":"2011-12-27 00:00:00"},
            {"PersonId":"12","0":"12","Name":"damir","1":"damir","Age":"27","2":"27","RecordDate":"2015-09-17 12:17:53","3":"2015-09-17 12:17:53"}
           ]
}
```

That shows every thing is correct, but jtable didn't show anything.

What am I doing wrong?

In `adminlayout.phtml` I use other jQuery functions in `$(document).ready` but when I deleted them it didn't work either.

```html
$(document).ready(function () {

//Prepare jTable
$('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable({
    title: 'Table of people',
    paging: true,
    pageSize: 2,
    sorting: true,
    defaultSorting: 'Name',
    actions: {
        listAction: root_url+'admin/index/personpagedsorted?action=list',
        },
    fields: {
        PersonId: {
            key: true,
            create: false,
            edit: false,
            list: false
        },
        Name: {
            title: 'Author Name',
            width: '40%'
        },
        Age: {
            title: 'Age',
            width: '20%'
        },
        RecordDate: {
            title: 'Record date',
            width: '30%',
            type: 'date',
            create: false,
            edit: false
        }

    }

});

//Load person list from server

$('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('load');
```

in controller: I only use list action.

```html
public function personpagedsortedAction()
{

     if ($_GET["action"]=="list")
    {
        $dbh=Zend_Registry::get('db');
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecordCount FROM people;");
        $sth->execute();
        $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

         $recordCount = $row['RecordCount'];
        $jtSorting=$_GET["jtSorting"];
       $jtStartIndex= $_GET["jtStartIndex"];
      $jtPageSize= $_GET["jtPageSize"];
        //Get records from database

     //  $result =$db->personselectinput($jtSorting, $jtStartIndex, $jtPageSize);

       $str_sql="SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY " . $jtSorting . " LIMIT " . $jtStartIndex . "," . $jtPageSize . ";";
       // $res=$db->query($str_sql);
       // $res=$db->fetchAll($str_sql);

       $sth = $dbh->prepare($str_sql);
       $sth->execute();

        //Add all records to an array
        $rows = array();

       while ( $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
       {
           $rows[]=$result;
       }

        //Return result to jTable
        $jTableResult = array();
        $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
        $jTableResult['TotalRecordCount'] = $recordCount;
        $jTableResult['Records'] = $rows;
     // i change print to echo and return but it didnt work too

      print json_encode($jTableResult);

    }
}
```

in edittest.phtml:
I wrote

```html
<div id="PeopleTableContainer"></div>
```

that show the table without any data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer
I disabled the layout of my action in controller and everything works great because when json returns it returns with the master layout and the response wasn't correct when i disabled the layout by adding new layout without any html tag it works.